# call a javascript function inside<script="text/javascript" src="/example.js">

Tags: javascript

Hi I am trying to call a function inside the `<script>` tag.
The formatLink function it is not being called. All other functions in jms.js can be called. How can i make it call functions in both jms.js and the one i declare in the script tags..

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jms.js">
function formatLink(cellvalue) {  return cellvalue+"working";}
 </script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Write it like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='javascript/jms.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  function formatLink(cellvalue) { return cellvalue+"working"; }
</script>
```

Comment: No problem, you should mark one of these answers as the accepted answer to neatly finish this question up.

Answer (score 1):

Each script have to be in it's own `<script>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jms.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function formatLink(cellvalue) {
         return cellvalue+"working"; 
    }
</script>
```